# How can I send a signal to a process ID in Perl 6?

Tags: signals, raku

Perl 6 has ways to [accept signals](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/signal) and to [send a signal to a Proc::Async](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Proc$COLON$COLONAsync#method_kill). Although the [p5-p6 perlfunc] docs says that kill works much like is does in Perl 5, it doesn't because you can't send a signal to an arbitrary process ID ([doc issue filed](https://github.com/perl6/doc/issues/1277)). I had a particular program I wanted to write in Perl 6 (for giggles), but was forced to fall back to Perl 5 for lack of a reliable [`kill`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/kill.html).

Short of shelling out to `kill` or `tasklist` (and `taskkill`), is this something we'll just have to do without. There's a kill in [S29](http://design.perl6.org/S29.html), but apparently not in the core docs. I haven't run across any docs of a more philosophical bent discussing what decisions drive various omissions.

I understand that a virtual machine that targets many systems has challenges when it comes to operating system specific stuff, but I don't know if that's the reason we can't have nice things such as `kill` (probably better named `signal` if you are starting over ;) and `exec`.

Answer (score 5):

I know you are looking for language support, but anyone finding this question who really needs a solution, can use NativeCall. For instance, to use the native `kill` on Linux (renamed to `syskill` for sanity):

```
use NativeCall;
# syskill( PID, SIGNAL ) -> 0 if sent, -1 if error, see "man 2 kill"
sub syskill(uint32, int32) returns int32 is native is symbol('kill') {};
```

Comment: I've thought about that, but I need it on Windows too. NativeCall is really cool though, but I fear the hated C situation of a long list of `#ifdef` to shim it for every system.