# How can I open a file for writing only when it doesn't exist in Perl 6?

Tags: raku

According to the open docs, there are adverbs for reading, writing, and appending. That's fine and what I would expect. I have a particular application that uses `sysopen` for better control and I was trying to rewrite it in Perl 6. I know about `NativeCall` (as mentioned in [my question about `kill`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43357541/2766176)), but is there something builtin that I'm missing?

Answer (score 8):

This is a case of incomplete documentation:

On MoarVM, `open` has supported the more common ones of the POSIX flags since 2015, including `O_EXCL` via the named parameter `:exclusive`.

The flag combination you're looking for is

```
my $fh = open "file", :mode<wo>, :create, :exclusive;
```

which can be written more compactly as

```
my $fh = open "file", :x;
```

This will hopefully be documented as part of the [ongoing grant](http://news.perlfoundation.org/2017/01/grant-proposal-standardization.html) *Standardization, Test Coverage, and Documentation of Perl 6 I/O Routines*. For now, details can be found in the [commit log](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/commit/36f773eb010df7c6b8bf0d431d209537a6061d15). There have been some minor changes since then; in particular, `:mode<pipe>` has been removed and a JVM implemetation added (which however does not allow you to combine flags as freely as MoarVM does).